# C++ CMake Build Errors "Undefined Reference"

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm quite new to CMake and I'm trying to build a cross-platform c++ project using VS2017 and the WSL (Linux Subsystem). Unfortunately I'm still trying to understand how CMake handles dependencies and linking so I'm having a lot of "unresolved external symbol" and "undefined reference to..." errors.

To make it simpler to understand I created the below project where I was able to replicate the kind of errors I'm having. Need some help to understand better how CMake can be configured.

Note: I've just included the opencv folder there to show how I'm trying to include external dependencies using CMake, despite the fact that I'm not really using any opencv code in this sample.

[image: Project Folder Structure]

/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(WslSample) set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/opencv/include )

add_subdirectory(src)
```

/src/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project (SampleApp)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES RELATIVE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} "src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS RELATIVE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} "src/*.hpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC utils)
```

/src/main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <log.hpp>

int main()
{
    log(LEVEL_INFO, "Sample App running...");
    return 0;
}
```

/utils/log.hpp

```
#pragma once

typedef enum
{
    LEVEL_DEBUG = 0,
    LEVEL_INFO = 1,
    LEVEL_WARNING = 2,
    LEVEL_ERROR = 3,
} LogLevel;

void log(const LogLevel& level, const char* str);
```

/utils/log.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <log.hpp>

std::string getLogStr(const LogLevel& level)
{
    switch (level)
    {
    case LEVEL_INFO:
        return "INFO";
    case LEVEL_DEBUG:
        return "DEBUG";
    case LEVEL_ERROR:
        return "ERROR";
    case LEVEL_WARNING:
        return "WARNING";
    default:
        return "n/a";
    }
}

void log(const LogLevel& level, const char* str) {
    std::cout << getLogStr(level) << " " << str << std::endl;
}
```

Build Output Logs

```
18:06:55: Copying files to remote machine...
18:06:55: Finished copying files (elapsed time 00h:00m:00s:009ms).
cd '/var/tmp/build/3df28527-45dd-1335-b3fd-743d2a9ed7dd/build/Linux-Debug';/usr/local/bin/cmake --build "/var/tmp/build/3df28527-45dd-1335-b3fd-743d2a9ed7dd/build/Linux-Debug" --target SampleApp  ;

[ 50%] Linking CXX executable SampleApp
CMakeFiles/SampleApp.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/var/tmp/src/3df28527-45dd-1335-b3fd-743d2a9ed7dd/Linux-Debug/src/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `log(LogLevel const&, char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/CMakeFiles/SampleApp.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'src/SampleApp' failed
make[3]: *** [src/SampleApp] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/SampleApp.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/SampleApp.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:97: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/SampleApp.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/SampleApp.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'SampleApp' failed
make: *** [SampleApp] Error 2

Build failed.
```

Comment: Looks like your `SOURCES` variable isn't picking up `/utils/log.cpp`. Try printing it out (I like to use `message(FATAL_ERROR "${SOURCES}")`

Comment: @Justin It was indeed an error related to the way I was looking for the files. Your tip helped me a lot to debug it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue... The way I was looking for the files was wrong and I was using the wrong CMake variable. Below the solution for this specific case:

#### /src/CMakeLists.txt

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES RELATIVE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} "*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS RELATIVE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} "*.hpp")
```